# OrderBy Enum but not by the value of my enum

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have a list of '''task''' that contains a priority enum variable. I need to order this list by priority but my priority rule is not based on enum value, enum name or enum description. My priority is based on rule that can change at any moment.

Let's say at this moment I must order all my task with the rule that say my tasks with PriorityType IZ = 3 must be at the end of my list. All other task has to be done first and there is no priority between all of them.

Another rule could be order task HT = 1 first then I don't care but RF = 4 at the end.

```
public enum PriorityType
    {
        [Description("who")]
        CL = 0,

        [Description("one")]
        HT = 1,

        [Description("exe)]
        SL = 2,

        [Description("bar")]
        IZ = 3,

        [Description("foo")]
        RF = 4
    }
```

There is no correlation and possibility to use the enumerator name, value or description and in my software priorities can change.

Using LINQ I did this but the result is not ordered

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new Dictionary<string, QueueType>();
    list.Add("one", QueueType.CL);
    list.Add("two", QueueType.CL);
    list.Add("three", QueueType.HT);
    list.Add("four", QueueType.IZ);
    list.Add("five", QueueType.RF);
    list.Add("six", QueueType.SL);

    list.OrderBy(y => y.Value == QueueType.HT)
        .ThenBy(y => y.Value == QueueType.RF);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public enum QueueType
{
    CL = 0,
    HT = 1,
    SL = 2,
    IZ = 3,
    RF = 4
}
```

[image]

Is this possible? 
Yes sure but is there an easy way? 
With LinQ?

Comment: It’s possible - it just means you need to implement your own `IComparer<T>` and pass that to `OrderBy`.

Comment: And note that linq operations do not mutate the source collection

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you expect the argument in the call to `OrderBy()` to select elements to move to the front. *That's not how it works.* Instead, this argument selects values to pass to a comparer function.

For the `OrderBy()` call in the question, when you have `QueueType.HT` you pass the value `true` to the comparer. If you have anything else, you pass the value `false` to the comparer. Honestly, I'm not sure what it will do with those `true`/`false` values, but if anything I'd expect the exact opposite order from what you wanted... that `false` would compare as a `0` value and `true` as a `1`, and you end up with the opposite order you intended. That's born out by [this example.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wVlYqB)

A better way to express the intent might look like this:

```
list.OrderBy(y => y.Value == QueueType.HT? 0 : y.Value == QueueType.RF? 1 : 2).Dump();
```

Though I'm not really a fan of nested ternary operators. It's the easiest way to get this into a single lambda expression, but I might rewrite this again into something more readable.

The point is at least now we have values for everything that makes numeric sense for sorting... but there's still a problem.

It's not clear here what that `Dump()` extension is doing, but the output image shown in the question looks a **LOT** like output from the Visual Studio debugger. You do know that those `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` calls **didn't change the original collection**, right? They return a sequence that loops over the collection in that order, but that actual collection is still unchanged. So if you're looking at the Visual Studio debugger here, *of course* what you see still matches the order you put in.

Comment: Oh sorry Dump() is comming from LINQPad. I always assume everybody knows this tool. You are right I should mention it or remove it from my samples. https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Gotcha.... I've used it, but it's been a looong time. Probably linqpad's `Dump()` is finding the original dictionary object for it's output... and dictionaries are **unordered** by definition. If you actually put your `OrderBy()` results into `foreach` loop you'll likely get results that make at least a little more sense... though, again, I think you've misunderstood how to use `OrderBy()`.

Comment: Smart solution. Why I'm not thinkin of that myself? I'm also not a fan of nested ternary operators but I see no better solution for now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be to encapsulate the priority logic into an `IComparer<QueueType>` implementation, which would be similar to a strategy-pattern.

For your example, you could go with something like this:

```
public class DictionaryComparer<TKey> : IComparer<TKey>
    {
        public DictionaryComparer(IDictionary<TKey, int> priorityMap, int defaultPriority)
        {
            // TODO: add validations
            this.PriorityMap = new Dictionary<TKey, int>(priorityMap);
            this.DefaultPriority = defaultPriority;
        }

        public int DefaultPriority{get;}

        public IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, int> PriorityMap{get;}

        public int Compare(TKey x, TKey y)
            => this.SafeAccess(x).CompareTo(this.SafeAccess(y));

        private int SafeAccess(TKey key) 
            => this.PriorityMap.TryGetValue(key, out var value)
               ? value 
               : this.DefaultPriority;
    }
```

And use it as follows:

```
var priorities = new Dictionary<QueueType, int>()
        {{QueueType.HT, 0}, {QueueType.RF, 1}};
var sorted = list.OrderBy(y => y.Value, new DictionaryComparer<QueueType>(priorities, int.MaxValue));
```

A working example can be found in [this netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NScNT6#)